# Blender AL lib: UpdateDeviceParams: Failed to set 44100hz, got 48000hz instead Windows

Tags: blender

Blender does not open.

```
AL lib: UpdateDeviceParams: Failed to set 44100hz, got 48000hz instead
```

Windows 10
64bit, same happens with 32bit installer
blender-2.79b-windows64.msi is what I installed.

My problem is that I cannot set 44100hz as mentioned in other posts under sound settings.

[image: Description: Selection options for sound settings for Dell computer]

Can I still use this software? How do I get it to work?
Can I start it with the command line and ignore the error somehow? If yes, how? I do not need sound.

Thank you.

Kind Regards.